# Time Out in SOA

Tags: java, timeout, weblogic, soa, bpel

I have an app deployed in weblogic server. In that app, I am calling an async webservice through a bpel in a composite. It is getting timed out after 5 minutes.
I tried adding the following code during the invoke activity:
bpelx:for="'PTM20'" 
But still timeout is 5 minutes.

Is there anything I need to do other than adding this? Is there any global SOA properties to modify?

I am invoking an aync webservice through a bpel like this:

```
< invoke name="myprocess"  inputVariable="varx"  operation="method" bpelx:for="'PTM20'" ....>
```

The exception I am getting is following:

```
<bpelFault><faultType>0</faultType>
<remoteFault xmlns="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension">
<part name="summary">
<summary>oracle.fabric.common.FabricInvocationException: Unable to invoke endpoint URI "my_webservice_url" successfully due to: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Message send failed: Read timed out</summary></part>
<part name="detail"><detail>Unable to invoke endpoint URI "my_webservice_url" successfully due to: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Message send failed: Read timed out</detail></part>
<part name="code"><code>null</code></part>
</remoteFault></bpelFault>
```

While going through Audit Trail, I can see the time difference between invocation and time out happened is 5 minutes. It did not wait for 20 minutes as expected.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Could you add some example code/settings file to illustrate exactly what you are doing, what exception you get and what settings you run (if appropriate)? It will help potential answerers better understand what's going on and therefore help them help you.

Comment: Thanks.
I have added the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple places to consider when configuring SOA/BPEL engine timeouts:

1. Domain wide global JTA timeout settings
2. individual BPEL engine EJB timeouts

Ideally you never want to hit those timeouts because you won't be able to do proper error handling. To avoid that you should set individual timeouts on outgoing references links and make sure they have smaller values than two mentioned above.

There are many blog posts available on this subject, for starters take a look at [this post](http://soadiscovery.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/soa-11g-configuring-transaction-timeout.html?m=1)

Comment: Thanks.
I went through the post and checked configuration in my dev server. None of these configurations are set as 5 mins.
Is there any other configuration I should check?
Also, the following line of code is of now use to change timeout of that invoke event?
bpelx:for="'PTM20'"

Thanks

Comment: I've added my answer before just before you included more details in your question. From exception you're getting I assuming you are calling some SOAP based web-service. To increase the timeout you should set "HTTP Read Timeout" property on reference link. This can be done in runtime thru EM console.

Comment: Yes. I think that's exactly the property I need to alter.
In the reference link, under EM console they have mentioned  SOA Administration –> BPEL properties.
I was unable to locate HTTP Read Timeout property there. Also I checked SoaInfraConfig.
Please help me locating this property in EM.
Thanks

Comment: find your composite in soa-infra, look at services and references, click on your reference, click on properties tab and you should see it. After you change it remember to hit "Apply"